# Go Test Coverage, over different packages

Tags: go, testing, code-coverage

I have been writing an rest service I have the following structure

```
/controllers
/domain/dao
/services
```

after writing a lot of tests for each individual package with mocks for each stage, I thought it would be quicker to just write tests against the controller and mock the database, so in that I know the /domain/dao layer is being called.

My problem now is when I run code coverage I do not get the coverage for my /service or the /domain/dao even though I know the code is being called

Any ideas on how to get my code coverage on all files?

Comment: Do not put controller, daos and services into different packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the flag `-coverpkg`

```
go test --cover -coverpkg=./services  ./... -coverprofile=cover.out
```

To check all the packages in the folder /services as well, you can try:

```
go test --cover -coverpkg=./services/...  ./... -coverprofile=cover.out
```

Just a side note - I usually add `-covermode=count`

```
go test --cover -covermode=count -coverpkg=./services/...  ./... -coverprofile=cover.out
```

Then, you can use go tool to see it as html:

```
go tool cover -html=cover.out
```

Comment: ah thanks this did work I guess I need some form of script to cover all packages into a single coverage