# go test coverage failing to build with test only packages

Tags: go, testing, code-coverage

When testing go files for go Test Coverage, over different packages i run this command -

Command got from this answer [code coverage over different packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842225/go-test-coverage-over-different-packages)

```
go test --cover -covermode=count  -coverpkg=./app_test/...  ./... -coverprofile=cover.out
```

but it's giving me `[build failed]`

After running the command my output is like this -

```
go build integration-test/app_test/metadata: no non-test Go files in /home/farhad/GoCodes/GPS-server/integration-test/app_test/metadata
go build integration-test/app_test/ping: no non-test Go files in /home/farhad/GoCodes/GPS-server/integration-test/app_test/ping
go build integration-test/app_test/ID: no non-test Go files in /home/farhad/GoCodes/GPS-server/integration-test/app_test/ID
go build integration-test/app_test/history: no non-test Go files in /home/farhad/GoCodes/GPS-server/integration-test/app_test/history
?       integration-test        [no test files]
FAIL    integration-test/app_test/ID [build failed]
?       integration-test/app_test/common        [no test files]
FAIL    integration-test/app_test/history [build failed]
FAIL    integration-test/app_test/metadata [build failed]
FAIL    integration-test/app_test/ping [build failed]
?       integration-test/domain [no test files]
?       integration-test/errors [no test files]
FAIL
```

how to get coverage over different packages?

This is my package structure -

```
├── app_test
│   ├── common
│   │   └── common.go
│   ├── history
│   │   └── history_test.go
│   ├── ID
│   │   └── id_test.go
│   ├── metadata
│   │   └── metadata_test.go
│   └── ping
│       └── ping_test.go
├── data
│   ├── locations.json
│   └── metadata.json
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── domain
│   ├── company.go
│   ├── history.go
│   ├── location.go
│   └── metadata.go
├── errors
│   └── rest_error.go
├── ex.txt
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── history_config.local.json
├── id_config.local.json
├── main.go
├── Makefile
├── metadata_config.local.json
├── ping_config.local.json
├── README.md
├── run.sh
```

Comment: Hey Inian, i just edited my question.

Comment: yes, it is working

Comment: Hey Inian, I just edited once more. please have a look.

Comment: go version : 1.16

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with test coverage but maybe with the test itself.
Can you cd into `integration-test/app_test/ID` folder and run `go test ...`

Comment: @AbuFarhad  Edit : `go test .`

Comment: same here, 
run this command - 
go test .  -cover    

coverage: [no statements]

Comment: Your getting `build failed` or `no test files` when running the command from `integration-test/app_test/ID` folder?

Comment: @AbuFarhad: Did the suggestions below solve your problem? If so you need to accept/upvote the answer

Comment: No, I tried this way but still facing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue that was fixed in release [go 1.17.3 onwards](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/c59b17e5a2244f7a99c440a07a1c174344da0ad8) because of [cmd/go: test coverpkg=all ./... with test only packages will fail to build #27333](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27333)

The gist of the issue is, packages failing to build if there are test only packages (without `.go` files) like in your case. There are couple of workarounds suggested in the thread.

Workaround - https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27333#issuecomment-770200300

> I've sent a fix above, which will presumably make it into Go 1.17. Until then, I agree with previous posters that the easiest workaround is to avoid test-only packages by dropping a no-op non-test file in those packages. For example: `echo "package foo" >foo/foo.go`. That workaround can be undone when the fix above ships in a stable release.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [go-acc](https://github.com/ory/go-acc) tool. That's how we do go accurate cross-package cover measurement.

So basically you will need just this:

```
$ goacc ./... -o=coverage.out
```